# Thumbnails of an image viewing tool(built using C# and .NET) refresh on every keystroke when opened in the web browser

Tags: c#, .net, lotus-notes

We have a web application developed using IBM Notes(Lotus Notes). The application is designed in such a way that when a Notes document is opened in the IE(version 11) browser, it opens with its respective Notes form and one or more images belonging to that Notes document. The image(s) gets displayed in a tool developed using C# and .NET. This tool is integrated with the Notes form. The issue faced here is, whenever we enter any data in the Notes form's fields, all the thumbnails of the image in the tool gets refreshed on every keystroke. This is very uncomfortable to use when the Notes document contains a large number of images. If the Notes document contains 20 images, all 20 thumbnails gets refreshed sequentially on every keystroke when entering data in the fields of the Notes form.

We have tried using the below mentioned piece of code, but it isn't helping.

`<meta charset="utf-8" 
       http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" 
       content="IE=5; IE=7; IE=8; IE=10; IE=11">`

Any suggestions on how to tackle this issue would be really appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the compatibility of few Active X Controls with IE-11 used in the C# and .Net application.

The issue was first suspected to be with rendering of javascript, but that wasn't the case as complete javascript code was removed from the Notes application and tested, only to find that still the reported issue was occurring.

These Active X Controls are used in the Imaging for Windows(developed by Global360). Imaging for Windows is a product which could be used(not available anymore) to develop image viewing and editing applications.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the fields on the form set to refresh automatically? There is a setting in the form properties for this.

Otherwise I would look at how that tool works. Is that something you created yourself, or is it a third party tool? Can you look at the source code for the page (HTML and Javascript) and see what it is doing? Have you used the developer tools in IE to see what they say?

And are you using `<!DOCTYPE html>` ?

Comment: The "Automatically refresh fields" is unchecked. Moreover, it is the thumbnails of the images which get refreshed and these thumbnails are part of the image tool which is just displayed alongside the Notes form. So even if the refresh setting is enabled, it shouldn't affect the thumbnails of images. The tool is not a third party tool, it is something which we have developed. <!DOCTYPE html> is used.

Comment: Then it sounds like it is the image tool that is triggered by keystrokes or updates/changes to the Notes UI document and refreshing the thumbnail. I would start looking in the code for that tool.

Comment: The issue doesn't occur when we open the application in IE-11.0.9600.18860 on a machine running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard. But it occurs when we open it in IE-11.15.16299.0 on a machine running Windows 10 OS. The different IE-11 subversion and the different OS got anything to do with this? Any browser settings which can deal with this? As already mentioned, the <meta> tag for IE-11 compatibility isn't helping.